# If all goes according to plan

Tags: phrase-meaning

Are "If all goes according to plan" and "If all goes as planned" interchangeable? The latter is what I would have written if I was the author. I am not sure they share the same meaning.

> On 18 February next year, a NASA spacecraft will plummet through the Martian atmosphere, fire its retro-rockets to break its fall and then lower a six-wheeled rover named Perseverance to the surface. **If all goes according to plan**, the mission will land in Jezero Crater, a 45-kilometre-wide gash near the planet’s equator that might once have held a lake of liquid water.

> Source: Nature  [How the first life on Earth survived its biggest threat — water](https://www.nature.com/articles/d41586-020-03461-4)    (Dec.9, 2020)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are interchangeable, yes. *To go according to plan* is a common phrase:

- Everything went according to plan; the wedding went off without a hitch.

I slightly prefer *everything* to *all* in both your sentences, but they are both commonly encountered.